# Set defaultValue for association field that targets a unique non-primary key

Tags: sql, sequelize.js, foreign-keys, associations, unique-key

I have two tables on Postgres:

```
class Account extends Model {
    static associate(models) {
      Account.belongsTo(models.Status, {
        targetKey: 'name',
        foreignKey: { name: 'status', allowNull: false, defaultValue: 'offline' },
      })
    }}

Account.init(
    {
      firstName: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
      lastName: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
      email: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false, unique: true },
      password: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false },
      image: DataTypes.STRING,
      telephone: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      tableName: 'accounts',
    },
)
```

```
  class Status extends Model {}
  Status.init(
    {
      name: { type: DataTypes.STRING, allowNull: false, unique: true },
    },
    {
      sequelize,
      tableName: 'statuses',
    },
  )
```

I want to set the default association `Status` for `Account` to be the record with the `name` "offline". And in top of that I want to reference not the primary key, but the unique value on the `name` column.

The generated query is:
`ALTER TABLE "accounts" ALTER COLUMN "status" SET NOT NULL;ALTER TABLE "accounts" ALTER COLUMN "status" SET DEFAULT 'offline' REFERENCES "statuses" ("name") ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE;ALTER TABLE "accounts" ALTER COLUMN "status" TYPE VARCHAR(255);`

But it throws the following error when doing Sequelize.sync() :
`syntax error at or near «REFERENCES»`

Comment: What DBMS do you have?

Comment: I'm using Postgres